# Second derivative and stationary points equalling zero

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f'(x_{s})=0$ (and $x_{s}$ is therefore a stationary point) is it always true that :

$$f''(x_{s})\ne0\,\, \forall x_{s}$$
Is this true for every $f(x)$ and if so how could I go about proving it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of easy counterexamples to this, where the stationary point can correspond to any of a maximum, minimum, or inflection point.

As a counterexample, take $$f(x) = x^4$$ Then it has a stationary point $x_s = 0$, but $f''(x_s) = 0$ (in this case, it is a minimum, you can do the same with $f(x) = -x^4$ to get a maximum, and similarly with $x^3$ gives an inflection point).